# ending txt contents in csv file by placing values in column format

Tags: unix, shell, shell-script, csv, sendmail

I would like to get help on sending below txt contents in csv file by placing values in column format

```
DEV-C axpp4-pkrisbtm 04-25-2018-01.15 04-25-2018-01.20
UAT AXKIN-PBBCT4 04-25-2018-22.02 04-25-2018-22.07
```

Currently, I am using below command which sends above content as attachment but in single row and column

```
uuencode  Availability.txt  AvailabilityReport.csv | mailx -r "abc.xyz@xyz.com" -s "Availability Report"  "abc.xyz@xyz.com"
```

Appreciate your help in advance .

Also, is it possible to add labels to columns?. I can add labels while sending report as HTML but not sure how to achieve same while sending as CSV

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To transform that into CSV, looks like you just want commas instead of spaces.

```
{
    echo 'Region,Server,Start DateTime,Stop DateTime'
    tr ' ' ',' < Availability.txt
} | mailx -r from -s subject recipient
```

I'm using the `{}` braces to group the echo and tr commands together, and then piping the output of that into mailx.

CSV has some edge cases, so this solution isn't foolproof.

Comment: Oops, it also sends the report as the message body, not as an attachment.